# Select last record created by user, by workstation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried using the search function for this, but none of the results give me anything I can use (although it may be user error - I'm fairly new to this).

What I'm trying to do is find the last record created per user per workstation. User and workstation are recorded in the table I'm selecting from. This is what I've got so far, and it selects everything between these date times. I want to narrow it down to just the last record for each "workstation", "Branch" and "inits".

```
    select workstation, 
           branch, 
           Inits, 
           document, 
           DateTime 
    from  iheads (nolock) 
    where Inits     = 'AAADB' 
    and  [datetime] >='2021-11-01 23:53:00.000' 
    AND  [datetime] <= '2021-11-30 23:58:00.000' 
    order by Workstation desc
```

I've included the document as a check, when this is working I'll remove it as it's not needed. Similarly, the Where is also just to narrow down my search results and to check the data - I'll be using a report program to fill in the where and date fields when live.

I've tried using "Top 1", but that only brings back one row, when there should be four (user has been on four different workstations in this selection criteria). Tried using Group By, but I keep getting the aggregate error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show schema, sample data and expected results.

Comment: You have tagged your request with the DBMS MySQL. But then you mention `TOP 1`, have brackets in your query and are using `NOLOCK` in your SQL (which you shouldn't!). It seems hence you are not using MySQL at all, but SQL Server.

Comment: I've changed the DBMS tag for you.

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). If you understand and accept the consequences, then at LEAST use current syntax and not deprecated syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an analytic function, e.g. `MAX OVER`, for this.

```
select *
from
(
  select
    ih.*,
    max(datetime) over (partition by workstation) as max_datetime_for_the_workstation
  from  iheads ih
  where ...
) with_max_datetime
where datetime = max_datetime_for_the_workstation
order by workstation;
```

As you have mentioned `TOP 1`in your request, here is how to do this with `TOP`: You want the top row per workstation, so you must rank the rows per workstation and pick the rows ranked #1. In order to retrieve all #1 rows, use `TOP WITH TIES`:

```
select top (1) with ties *
from iheads
where ...
order by rank() over (partition by workstation order by datetime desc);
```

Answer (score 0):

The weird thing about SQL tables? They are *unordered sets* of rows. So, when you say "last record" you actually mean "record with largest value of `datetime` column.

Let us find those largest values  for each combination

```sql
                  SELECT MAX([DateTime]) DateTime,
                         workstation, branch, Inits
                    FROM iheads
                   WHERE /* whatever filter criteria you require */
                   GROUP BY workstation, branch, Inits
                   ORDER BY workstation DESC
```

If that gets the result you want, great.

But if you need other columns from the rows, let's use the query as a subquery. W'll join it to the detail table to find the rows with matching data

```sql
SELECT a.workstation, 
       a.branch, 
       a.Inits, 
       a.document, 
       a.[DateTime]
  FROM iheads a
  JOIN (  /* the subquery */
                  SELECT MAX([DateTime]) DateTime,
                         workstation, branch, Inits
                    FROM iheads
                   WHERE /* whatever filter criteria you require */
                   GROUP BY workstation, branch, Inits
       ) b   ON a.workstation=b.workstation
            AND a.branch=b.branch
            AND a.Inits=b.Inits
            AHD a.[DateTime]=b.[DateTime]
 ORDER BY workstation DESC
```

**Pro tip:** Avoid mixed case in table and column names. You don't want to wonder whether your RDBMS is case-sensitive, or not.

**Pro tip:** Avoid reserved words (datetime, for example) in column names.

**Pro tip:** You're new to this. Stuff like `(nolock)` is for experts to use to solve performance and deadlocking problems. Don't use that kind of stuff without specific instructions from an expert who has examined your query's execution plan.

By the way, this is [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server), not [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql).

Comment: If the datetime is not guaranteed to be unique per workstation (or by workstation + branch + inits in your query), you'll have to apply the same `WHERE` clause in the main query, too. You can avoid this by putting the base query in a CTE (`WITH` clause). But usually top n per group tasks are solved with windws functions (`ROW_NUMBER|RANK|MAX|... OVER`) nowadays.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much! That first result gets me the answers I was trying to get, checked it all through my programs front end and it matches! Now to get this into the reporting software so I can search criteria properly... :D 

Unfortunately I can't do anything about the mixed case/reserved names, the database I'm using was created by a third party, I'm trying to interrogate the data and create reports based on what we have.

Comment: Also, I was told (nolock) would stop the table from being locked when running potentially large queries. As this is live data, I thought it'd be necessary to stop me preventing users recording to the table. But I appreciate the help and advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the row_number=1 via a `top 1 with ties`

```
select top 1 with ties
  workstation,
  branch,
  Inits,
  document,
  [DateTime]
from iheads
where Inits = 'AAADB' 
  and [Datetime] >= cast('2021-11-01 23:53' as datetime)
  and [Datetime] <= cast('2021-11-30 23:58' as datetime)
order by row_number() over (partition by workstation, branch, Inits
                            order by [Datetime] desc)
```